# Read all incoming and outgoing mail in a network

Tags: outlook, email

Can an administrator - with the knowledge of the employees - read incoming and outgoing messages using a simple configuration on Outlook?

Comment: The ethics of such a move are HIGHLY questionable!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, given a simple configuration with Exchange and Outlook, for an Exchange admin to read user's mail, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it on outlook is probably going to be excessively messy, probably needs to be done on eash and every system and there's probably an easier way to do it on your mail server. This will, also, possibly fall afoul of some local privacy laws, but IANAL. As commenters have mentioned, this is likely to be not very ethical.

Assuming you want to do it in outlook, [outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/automatically-forward-messages-to-another-e-mail-account-HA001150201.aspx) actually supports forwarding all messages that come into it - you just need to create a rule that forwards or redirects all incoming messages, and a [second one that forwards all sent messages](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/automatically-send-someone-a-copy-of-messages-that-you-send-HA010239583.aspx).

In both cases, rules and alerts is your friend.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that any technically competent user will be able to bypass this eavesdropping.